# Download website with page requisites but only images and css

Tags: wget

I'm using a `wget` command which downloads an entire webpage with all assets, requisites and save it to custom folder for a later work on it.

My actual code:

```
$ wget --adjust-extension --span-hosts --convert-links --page-requisites \
 --no-directories --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent \
 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"\
 ‐‐execute robots=off --limit-rate 400k --directory-prefix=elbache \
 ‐‐output-document=index.html http://www.bachecubano.com/celulares
```

By now everything works great, but I want to reduce the `--page-requisites` to only CSS and images (I don't want .JS files). The downloaded pages can be reduced by almost 40% if I don't load .js assets, which is not required for my purpose.

How do I config `wget` for only accept *.css and /images* but not *.js files?

Comment: there is an `-A` and `-R` option for accept/reject file types list.  You can either accept the html, css, and images or reject javascript files.

Comment: examples please? I'm not expert.

Comment: The man page makes it pretty clear - https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options

Answer (score 2):

From the `wget` man page:

```
   -A acclist --accept acclist
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to 
       accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, 
       *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be
       treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.
```

So you'd add the following switch to what you already have:

```
-A css,png,jpg,gif,jpeg
```

**NOTE:** You'll have to play with this and figure out what image formats this particular site uses.